# Pending Intent causes delay

Tags: android

Trying to set multiple Alarms using Pending Intent, However The Alarms does not broadcast in The correct time. What might be causing this ?

```
public void clicker (View view)
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddAlarm.this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                                      int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

                    int c_hour,c_min;
                    String format;
                    c_hour=selectedHour;
                    c_min=selectedMinute;

                    if (c_hour == 0) {
                        c_hour += 12;
                        format = "AM";
                    } else if (c_hour == 12) {
                        format = "PM";
                    } else if (c_hour > 12) {
                        c_hour -= 12;
                        format = "PM";
                    } else {
                        format = "AM";
                    }

                    String formatTime = String.format("%02d : %02d %s", c_hour, c_min, format);

                    TextView dimple = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                    dimple.setText(formatTime);
                    setAlarm(calendar);

                }
            }, hour, minute, false);// Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();

}

private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal)
{


    Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);


}
```

This is how I set the alarm, Also The pending intents are uniquely set as system time in ms, There is no warning or error in logcat, alarms work fine, the only problem is not in time, expected one or 2 mins of delay? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try to use alarmManager.setExact() as the common set-method is inexact starting with API-Level 19. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: @Christopher That looks promising , but how do I alter my code with Exact(), having trouble :(

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand? Simply use alarmManager.setExact instead of alarmManager.set and add a SDK-Version switch.

Answer (score 0):

After using `Calendar.getInstance();` in `onTimeSet` use `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Maybe this will help. Also make sure to use different requestCodes for pending intents in case of multiple alarms

Answer (score 0):

Since API-Level 19 the alarms are per default inexact. You could use setExact()-method instead.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
} else {
     am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender;
}
```

You will find further information here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: I tried, but again seems to have no effect! The alarm takes around an additional one min to launch, There are total of 4 alarms , max that can be set. And if I set all 4, one after the other, then it takes more than 4 min to play the initial alarm, then after an interval of one min, the other alarms play